# Apply multiple expression in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Having different kind of filter following used in different situation. How to apply more than 1 filter in a LinQ.

```
Expression<Func<data, bool>> filter =
                    bt => bt.condition1 == condition1;
Expression<Func<data, bool>> filter2 =
                    bt => bt.condition2 == condition2;
Expression<Func<data, bool>> filter3 =
                    bt => bt.condition3 == condition3;


var result = dataList.Where(filter1);
var result2 = dataList.Where(filter2, filter3); //Syntax error
var result3 = dataList.Where(filter2).Where(filter3); //Is this proper?
var result4 = dataList.Where(filter2 || filter3); //Syntax error
```

Comment: Can't you simply call `dataList.Where(filter1).Where(filter2).Where(filter3)`?

Comment: To your edit: Why should this solution be proper? It basically filters the elements and the elements that match the filter are filtered again.

Comment: Can the conditions not be aggregated? Then it's just a single Where

Comment: Is that `dataList.Where(filter1 [&&/||] filter2 [&&/||] filter3)` enough? To combine between filters you can use AND/OR boolean comparison, or use consecutive 3 `Where` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `.Where(filter)` for every filter that you want to apply.

You can filter the `IEnumerable<T>` that `.Where()` returns again, filtering out all elements that you want.

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<someType> result = dataList.Where(filter1).Where(filter2).Where(filter3);
```

What you could do aswell is have all the filtering conditions in a single expression, instead of multiple ones.

Comment: Is this the same as `dataList.Where(bt => bt.condition1 == condition1 &&  bt.condition2 == condition2 && bt.condition3 && bt.condition3);` when there are multiple where

Comment: @Z.V If these are your filters, yes. The boolean values you get from the comparison only evaluates to true if ALL the conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of `dataList`.

If it's `IEnumerable<data>`, then you can use functions instead of expressions, and a lambda function for the [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) clause:

```
Func<data, bool> filter =  (bt => bt.condition1 == condition1);
Func<data, bool> filter2 = (bt => bt.condition2 == condition2);
Func<data, bool> filter3 = (bt => bt.condition3 == condition3);

var all = dataList.Where(d => filter1(d) && filter2(d) && filter3(d));
var any = dataList.Where(d => filter1(d) || filter2(d) || filter3(d));
```

However if the type is `IQueryable<data>`, then you will need to use multiple calls to the Queryable version of [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var all = dataList.Where(filter1).Where(filter2).Where(filter3);

var any = dataList.Where(filter1)
                  .Union(dataList.Where(filter2))
                  .Union(dataList.Where(filter3))
                  .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practies,

```
var query = fooContext.User.AsQueryable();

if (condition1!= null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.condition1==condition1);
if (condition2 != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.condition2== condition2 );

return await query.ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure the concept of asynchronicity is relevant to this particular question. Nor am I convinced about 'best practies'

Comment: Sorry. I copied the code from my project. I forgot to change. I've update my response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the conditions using and you can just use several where operators:

```
// equivalent to filter1 && filter2 && filter3
var result = dataList.Where(filter1).Where(filter2).Where(filter3);
```

If you want to combine the filters using or it is a bit more complicated, you need to manually manipulate the expressions, I have this small util that can do that:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombineWithOr<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] filters)
{
    var first = filters.First();
    var param = first.Parameters.First();
    var body = first.Body;

    foreach(var other in filters.Skip(1))
    {
        var replacer = new ReplaceParameter
        {
            OriginalParameter = other.Parameters.First(),
            NewParameter = param
        };
        // We need to replace the original expression parameter with the result parameter
        body = Expression.Or(body, replacer.Visit(other.Body));
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        body,
        param
    );
}
class ReplaceParameter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression OriginalParameter { get; set; }
    public Expression NewParameter { get; set; }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == this.OriginalParameter ? this.NewParameter : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// equivalent to filter1|| filter2 || filter3
var result4 = dataList.Where(CombineWithOr(filter1, filter2, filter3));
```